# Testing Parsec parsers by generating inputs with QuickCheck

Tags: testing, haskell, parsec, quickcheck

I'd like to write tests for a suite of Parsec parsers. Here's a simple example of a parser I want to test with QuickCheck:

```
identifier = do
  c <- letter
  cs <- many (alphaNum <|> oneOf identSymbols)
  skipSpaces
  return $ Ident $ c:cs
```

So, ideally, I'd want QuickCheck to generate valid identifiers and make sure I get the right results back, as well as generating invalid identifiers and making sure they return `ParseError`. Are there any utilities that would make this sort of thing easier? Is there a way I can "run my parser in reverse", so to speak, to generate such inputs?

In general, what would a good suite of QuickCheck tests for this parser look like? To some extent, it seems like I'd basically have to duplicate the logic of the parser in QuickCheck to achieve a thorough test. Is that really a good idea, or this perhaps a situation where a more traditional tool like HUnit is more suitable than QuickCheck?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, the reverse of a parser is a pretty printer, and the reverse of random input to a parser, is random pretty printing of an AST.

So, follow the [usual approach](http://lstephen.wordpress.com/2007/07/29/parsec-parser-testing-with-quickcheck/) and define an Arbitrary instance for your AST, which drives random well-formed syntax fragments. Mix in some erroneous characters as a wrapper to test for error handling.

See also:

- [Automated Testing of Java ABNF Grammar Parsers with QuickCheck](https://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/2077/4579/4/gupea_2077_4579_4.pdf)
- [Automatic Testing of Higher Order Functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20061010040723/http://www.st.cs.ru.nl/papers/2006/koop2006-TestingOfHigherOrderFunctionsAPLAS.pdf) - parser testing in Clean with QC.

Comment: A particular property that i like to use is that parse = parse . pretty . parse. This serves as a decent way to model the quotienting of information by the parser, there is a nice adjunction to drive it from a theoretical perspective, and it captures the fact that pretty . parse is idempotent, if not the identity function. (Usually parsing discards some information)

Comment: last two links are dead

Comment: @AlexHirzel Fixed! (pending approval)